# How to call an directory when saving

Tags: ios, directory, save

II have created multiple directories like this

```
NSArray *directoryNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hats",@"bottoms",@"right",@"left",nil];
```

however I do not know how to save into a specific directory.I save like this

```
NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; 
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(captureImage.image);
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

However I do not know how to specify the directory.  I only want the user to save into directory hats.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *imageCacheDirPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hats"];
NSString *imageCachePath = [imageCacheDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMAGE_NAME_HERE.PNG"]; 

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: imageCacheDirPath])
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imageCacheDirPath 
                                withIntermediateDirectories:NO 
                                                 attributes:nil
                                                      error:NULL];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:imageCachePath 
                                        contents:dataObj 
                                      attributes:nil];
```